# ASP.Net Regex Example

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a regex code which will detect format like this "1-2-2-2-1-5".This can be longer string or shorter like "1-8-5-6".I mean, the length is not entirely clear.But format is certain one int and one '-'. i tried "(^[-][0-9]){,}" this.But i have no idea about Regex. Can someone help me?Thnx.

Comment: what happened when you tried that?

Comment: nothing, only pattern not matches with my string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regex:

```
^[0-9](?:-[0-9])*$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/sMMkMzQVd8)

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug.
My question missing.
In situation "1-12-12-1" regex is not matched.
So I changed my regex with "^(\d+(-\d+)*)?$".